# Rollback transactions not working with py.test and Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, pytest

I'm using py.test to test my Flask application but I am getting IntegrityError because I am creating the same model in two different tests.

I am using postgreSQL 9.3.5 and Flask-SQLAlchemy 1.0.

**EDIT I've updated my sessoin fixture with Jeremy Allen's answer and it fixed a lot of the errors. However it seems when I use the user fixture that I still get IntegrityErrors**

**Error**

```
E       IntegrityError: (IntegrityError) duplicate key value violates unique constraint "ix_users_email"
E       DETAIL:  Key (email)=(not_used@example.com) already exists.
E        'INSERT INTO users (email, username, name, role_id, company_id, password_hash, confirmed, member_since, last_seen) VALUES (%(email)s, %(username)s, %(name)s, %(role_id)s, %(company_id)s, %(password_hash)s, %(confirmed)s, %(member_since)s, %(last_seen)s) RETURNING users.id' {'username': 'not_used', 'confirmed': True, 'name': 'To be Removed', 'member_since': datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 29, 19, 19, 41, 7929), 'company_id': None, 'role_id': 3, 'last_seen': datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 29, 19, 19, 41, 7941), 'email': 'not_used@example.com', 'password_hash': 'pbkdf2:sha1:1000$cXUh6GbJ$6f38242871cff5e4cce4c1dc49a62c4aea4ba1f3'}
```

**conftest.py**

```
@pytest.yield_fixture(scope='session')
def app():
    app = create_app('testing')
    app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = 'example.com:1234'
    ctx = app.app_context()
    ctx.push()
    app.response_class = TestResponse
    app.test_client_class = TestClient
    yield app
    ctx.pop()


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def db(app):
    _db.drop_all()
    _db.create_all()

    Permission.insert_initial()
    Role.insert_initial()
    Technology.insert_initial()
    Product.insert_initial()
    Actor.insert_initial()
    Industry.insert_initial()
    DeliveryCategory.insert_initial()
    DeliveryMethod.insert_initial()

    user = User(email='admin@example.com', username='admin', confirmed=True, password='admin', name='Admin')
    user.role = Role.query.filter_by(name='Administrator').first()
    _db.session.add(user)
    _db.session.commit()

    return _db


@pytest.yield_fixture(scope='function')
def session(db):
    db.session.begin_nested()
    yield db.session
    db.session.rollback()


@pytest.yield_fixture(scope='function')
def user(session):
    yield session.query(User).filter_by(email='admin@example.com').first()


@pytest.yield_fixture(scope='function')
def client(app, user):
    client = app.test_client()
    client.auth = 'Basic ' + b64encode((user.email + ':' + 'admin').encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')
    yield client
```

**Tests that fail**

```
def test_edit_agenda_add_company_rep_without_company(session, client, user):
    user2 = User(name='To be Removed', password='not_used', username='not_used', confirmed=True,
                email='not_used@example.com', role=Role.query.filter_by(name='User').first())
    agenda = Agenda(name='Invalid Company Rep', creator=user)
    session.add(agenda)
    session.commit()

    response = client.jput('/api/v1.0/agendas/%s' % agenda.id,
        data={
            'company_representative': user2.id
        }
    )
    assert response.status_code == 200

def test_edit_agenda_add_user_already_in_agenda(session, client, user):
    user2 = User(name='To be Removed', password='not_used', username='not_used', confirmed=True,
                email='not_used@example.com', role=Role.query.filter_by(name='User').first())
    agenda = Agenda(name='Invalid Company Rep', creator=user)
    agenda.users.append(user2)
    session.add(agenda)
    session.commit()

    response = client.jput('/api/v1.0/agendas/%s' % agenda.id,
        data={
            'users': [user2.id]
        }
    )
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

**Tests that pass**

```
def test_get_agenda_modules_where_agenda_that_does_not_exist(session, app):
    # Create admin user with permission to create models
    user = User(email='admin2@example.com', username='admin2', confirmed=True, password='admin2')
    user.role = Role.query.filter_by(name='Administrator').first()
    session.add(user)
    session.commit()

    client = app.test_client()
    client.auth = 'Basic ' + b64encode(
        (user.email + ':' + 'admin2').encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')
    response = client.jget('/api/v1.0/agenda-modules/%s/%s' % (5, 4))
    assert response.status_code == 404

def test_get_agenda_modules_agenda_modules_does_not_exist(session, app):
    agenda = Agenda(name='Is tired in the AM')
    session.add(agenda)

    # Create admin user with permission to create models
    user = User(email='admin2@example.com', username='admin2', confirmed=True, password='admin2')
    user.role = Role.query.filter_by(name='Administrator').first()
    session.add(user)
    session.commit()

    client = app.test_client()
    client.auth = 'Basic ' + b64encode(
        (user.email + ':' + 'admin2').encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')
    response = client.jget('/api/v1.0/agenda-modules/%s/%s' % (agenda.id, 4))
    assert response.status_code == 400
    assert response.jdata['message'] == 'AgendaModule does not exist.'
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to [join a Session into an External Transaction](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session.html?highlight=testing%20transactions#joining-a-session-into-an-external-transaction-such-as-for-test-suites) and you are using flask-sqlalchemy.

Your code is not working as expected because the session actually ends up using a different connection to the one you are beginning the transaction on.

#### 1. You need to bind the Session to the Connection

As in the example linked above. A quick change to your code in conftest.py should do it:

```
@pytest.yield_fixture(scope='function')
def session(db):
    ...
    session = db.create_scoped_session(options={'bind':connection})
    ...
```

**Unfortunately**, due to flask-sqlalchemy's [SignallingSession](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/2.0/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py#L136) (as at v2.0), your 'bind' argument will be overruled!

This is because SignallingSession set the 'binds' argument such that it will take precedence over our 'bind' argument and it doesn't offer us a nice way to specify our own 'binds' argument.

There is a [GitHub pull request](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/pull/168) from December 2013 where someone else had the same problem.

#### 2. Tweak flask-sqlalchemy

We can subclass SignallingSession to allow us to do what we want:

```
class SessionWithBinds(SignallingSession):
    """The extends the flask-sqlalchemy signalling session so that we may
    provide our own 'binds' argument.
    """

    def __init__(self, db, autocommit=False, autoflush=True, **options):
        #: The application that this session belongs to.
        self.app = db.get_app()
        self._model_changes = {}
        #: A flag that controls whether this session should keep track of
        #: model modifications.  The default value for this attribute
        #: is set from the ``SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS`` config
        #: key.
        self.emit_modification_signals = \
            self.app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS']
        bind = options.pop('bind', None) or db.engine
        # Our changes to allow a 'binds' argument
        try:
            binds = options.pop('binds')
        except KeyError:
            binds = db.get_binds(self.app)
        SessionBase.__init__(self, autocommit=autocommit, autoflush=autoflush,
                             bind=bind,
                             binds=binds, **options)
```

And then subclass SQLAlchemy (the main flask-sqlalchemy class) to use our SessionWithBinds in place of SignallingSession

```
class TestFriendlySQLAlchemy(SQLAlchemy):
    """For overriding create_session to return our own Session class"""

    def create_session(self, options):
        return SessionWithBinds(self, **options)
```

Now you have to use this class in place of SQLAlchemy:

```
db = TestFriendlySQLAlchemy()
```

And finally, back in our conftest.py specify a new 'binds':

```
@pytest.yield_fixture(scope='function')
def session(db):
    ...
    session = db.create_scoped_session(options={'bind':connection, 'binds':None})
    ...
```

Now your transactions should rollback as expected.

#### This is all a bit complicated...

Instead of doing all this you could try using [`Session.begin_nested`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html?highlight=begin_nested#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.begin_nested). It requires that your database supports SQL SAVEPOINTs (PostgreSQL does).

Change your conftest.py fixture:

```
@pytest.yield_fixture(scope='function')
def session(db):
    db.session.begin_nested()
    yield db.session
    db.session.rollback()
```

More info on using `SAVEPOINT`s in SQLAlchemy: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_transaction.html#using-savepoint

This is pretty simple but will work as long as the code you are testing doesn't call `rollback` itself. If this is a problem take a look at the code [here in the SQLAlchemy docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session.html#joining-a-session-into-an-external-transaction-such-as-for-test-suites) under the title "Supporting Tests with Rollbacks"

Comment: I updated my question. It seems there is a problem with the user fixture or how I am using it. Maybe you have some insight.

Comment: Just checking if the env var ```SQLALCHEMY_BINDS``` might do what you require?

Comment: @Jeremy do you mind updating this answer now that Flask-SQLAlchemy 2.1 supports the `binds` parameter and doesn't need subclassing?

Comment: One potential gotcha with `SAVEPOINT` is sequences (such as PK ID assignment) aren't reset. So if your tests are run in random order, the PK ID of inserted objects will be uknown.

Comment: Here is [the latest link regarding joining a session into an external transaction](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_transaction.html#joining-a-session-into-an-external-transaction-such-as-for-test-suites)

Answer (score 6):

The key here is to run your tests within a nested session, and then rollback everything after the execution of each test (this also assumes there are no dependencies across your tests).

I suggest adopting the following approach, by running each of your tests within a nested transaction:

```
# module conftest.py
import pytest

from app import create_app
from app import db as _db
from sqlalchemy import event
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def app(request):
    """
    Returns session-wide application.
    """
    return create_app("testing")


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def db(app, request):
    """
    Returns session-wide initialised database.
    """
    with app.app_context():
        _db.drop_all()
        _db.create_all()


@pytest.fixture(scope="function", autouse=True)
def session(app, db, request):
    """
    Returns function-scoped session.
    """
    with app.app_context():
        conn = _db.engine.connect()
        txn = conn.begin()

        options = dict(bind=conn, binds={})
        sess = _db.create_scoped_session(options=options)

        # establish  a SAVEPOINT just before beginning the test
        # (http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_transaction.html#using-savepoint)
        sess.begin_nested()

        @event.listens_for(sess(), 'after_transaction_end')
        def restart_savepoint(sess2, trans):
            # Detecting whether this is indeed the nested transaction of the test
            if trans.nested and not trans._parent.nested:
                # The test should have normally called session.commit(),
                # but to be safe we explicitly expire the session
                sess2.expire_all()
                sess2.begin_nested()

        _db.session = sess
        yield sess

        # Cleanup
        sess.remove()
        # This instruction rollsback any commit that were executed in the tests.
        txn.rollback()
        conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really said what you use to manage the database, there is no clue what library is behind `_db` or any of the model classes.

But regardless of that I would suspect that the `session.commit()` call is likely involved in the reason the transaction gets committed.  Ultimately you'll have to read the docs on what `session.commit()` does in the framework you're using.

Comment: I'm using Flask-SQLAlchemy