# Roll back main code database session in flask-sqlalchemy after each test

Tags: postgresql, flask, pytest, flask-sqlalchemy, rollback

### Context

I have a quite big test suite to optimize and the biggest bottleneck I found is that the tables are being dropped and recreated on every test. If this drop and create is done only once for the whole test session, the execution time of the suite drops **4 times** so for me it is essential to switch to rollbacks on every test.

This is the fixture that is used on every test to drop tables, recreate, and add some data

```py
from xxx.main import db

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def app():
    from xxx.main import application

    return TestApp(application)

# Every test uses the following fixture
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def drop_and_create(app):
    engine = create_engine("url_to_postgres")
    m = MetaData()
    m.reflect(engine)
    m.drop_all(engine)

    db.create_all()
    db.session.commit()
    # add some test data below
```

The application uses `flask-sqlalchemy` for defining models and transactions with a `posgresql` database

```py
# model definition
from xxx import db

class ModelName(db.Model):
...
```

The `db` variable is defined as follows

```py
import connexion
from flask_migrate import Migrate
app = connexion.App(__name__)
application = app.app
db = create_db(application)
migrate = Migrate(app=application, db=db)
metadata = db.metadata
```

```py
def create_db():
    # some configurations such as
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = ...
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS"] = {
        "pool_recycle": app.config["SA_POOL_RECYCLE"],
        "pool_pre_ping": True,
    }
    db = SQLAlchemy(
        app,
        session_options={
            "autoflush": True,
            "autocommit": False,
            "expire_on_commit": False,
        },
    )
    db.init_app(app)
    return db
```

### What is the problem?

The problem is that I cannot roll back the changes made in the **main code**. For example, `db` transactions made in the test body itself would be rolled back

```py
from xxx.main import db
def test_smth(app):
    response = cms_app.post(
        params=json.dumps(..),
        url="/register-user",                # Any transactions made in the body of the
        headers=headers,                     # endpoint handler are NOT rolled back
        expect_errors=True,
        content_type="application/json",
    )
   
    db.add(something) 
    db.session.commit() # This will be rolled back
```

```py
from xxx.main import db
# Endpoint definition
@blueprint.route("/register-user", methods=["POST"])
def registerUser():
    db.add(..)
    db.commit(...)   # None of those transactions are rolled back after the test.
```

### What did I try?

I dug for possible solutions related to my problem. The following solution is close to what I need - it rolls back all transactions made in the **test body** but not in the **main code**. Tests are very quick but some fail because data is persisted in the database. When I check the tables with `pgAdmin` after the tests have run, there is data left.

```py
# Fixture is added to every test
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def db_session(app):
    """
    It creates a nested transaction, recreates it when the application code
    calls session.commit and rolls it back at the end.
    """
    connection = db.engine.connect()
    transaction = connection.begin()
    db.session = db.create_scoped_session(options={'bind': connection})
 
    # Begin a nested transaction (using SAVEPOINT).
    nested = connection.begin_nested()
 
    # If the application code calls session.commit, it will end the nested
    # transaction. Need to start a new one when that happens.
    @listens_for(db.session, "after_transaction_end")
    def end_savepoint(session, transaction):
        nonlocal nested
        if not nested.is_active:
            nested = connection.begin_nested()
 
    yield
 
    # Rollback the overall transaction, restoring the state before the test ran.
    db.session.close()
    transaction.rollback()
    connection.close()
```

I found that https://github.com/jeancochrane/pytest-flask-sqlalchemy/issues/28 has a similar problem to min but I could not fit their solution to my needs. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26624146/9553927 also seems like a similar problem but they want to roll back transactions from the **test code**, not the **main code**.

Any help is appreciated.